# Accessing javascript object from two different renderers in electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an electron application where I raise a window in main process and run a `renderer1`. I have an object `obj1` that's instantiated in renderer1.
I have a protocol which launches another browser window(same main process) from `renderer1` which runs it's own `renderer2`. Now, I want to access the object obj1  in `renderer2`. Is this possible ?
I'm running this on windows 10. If running another browser window is not a good idea can i raise a regular window(NOT browser window) in renderer1 and access the object from this window ?
Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try to did-finish load event of renderer 2 window and pass a  object1 using IPC communication like this.

```html
// second window object

 this.win2.webContents.on(
          'did-finish-load', () => {                  
             this.win2.webContents.send('object1', object1);
          }
)
```

Comment: Do you mean i have to send the object1 to main and then ipc it to renderer2 ? I'm trying to export it from the renderer1 JS and access it from renderer2 JS, it doesn't work. is this correct ?

Comment: No its not correct because all windows work independent so we can not access the data directly. we need to use ipc communication to share object between all the windows.

Comment: Thanks, understand that. Now, if i share the object this way through IPC is the state of the object visible to renderer2 if it is being dynamically updated in renderer1 ?

Comment: Not dynamically updated we need to send on every update